# Changing an if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please give me your lights. I am using some javascript for the behavior of one form. As you can see on the code that i provide below, if the form is submited successfully, a message is displayed. What i need is instead of this message, a URL to open. I guess the change has to be made in the if (resp.result=="success") . Note also that the else condition have to be the same

```
function mce_success_cb(resp){
    $('#mce-success-response').hide();
    $('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result=="success"){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
            if (parts[1]==undefined){
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try{
            if (index== -1){
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = $(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                    f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f){
                    $(f).append(html);
                    $(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i need is instead of this message, a URL to open.

OK, so replace the part of the code you don't need with this:

```
window.location = "yourURLhere";
```

[More information from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

If your intention was to open a page in a new window then try this:

```
window.open("yourURLhere", "AWindowName", strWindowFeatures);
```

Where `strWindowFeatures` is an optional parameter that lets you set the size, position, etc. for the new window. See MDN for complete [doco on `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Comment: Sure that works! the window.location command is only opening in new window? are any options for parent?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question you just need a:

```
window.location = 'http://www.domain.com';
```

line inside your `if (resp.result=="success"){` block.